# Why the first item of the list is displayed all the on the opened sheet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am passing binding variable into other view:

```
struct PocketlistView: View {

    @ObservedObject var pocket = Pocket()
    @State var isSheetIsVisible = false


    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(Array(pocket.pockets.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { (index, pocketItem) in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text(pocketItem.name).font(.headline)
                        Text(pocketItem.type).font(.footnote)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.isSheetIsVisible.toggle()
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: self.$isSheetIsVisible){
                        PocketDetailsView(pocketItem: self.$pocket.pockets[index])
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Pockets")
        }
    }
}
```

the other view is:

```
struct PocketDetailsView: View {

    @Binding var pocketItem: PocketItem

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(pocketItem.name)")
    }
}
```

Why I see the first item when i open sheet for second or third row?
When I use NavigationLink instead of the .sheet it works perfect

Answer (score 1):

You activate all sheets at once, try the following approach (I cannot test your code, but the idea should be clear)

```swift
struct PocketlistView: View {

    @ObservedObject var pocket = Pocket()
    @State var selectedItem: PocketItem? = nil


    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(Array(pocket.pockets.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { (index, pocketItem) in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text(pocketItem.name).font(.headline)
                        Text(pocketItem.type).font(.footnote)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedItem = pocketItem
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Pockets")
            .sheet(item: self.$selectedPocket) { item in
                PocketDetailsView(pocketItem: 
                    self.$pocket.pockets[self.pocket.pockets.firstIndex(of: item)!])
            }

        }
    }
}
```